# Preventing a context menu within a context menu EXT js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I can customize the first instance of a context menu but if I hover over that context menu and right click, it brings up a default context menu. How would I stop that menu from showing up. This code is how I customized the first menu

```
grid.on('itemcontextmenu', function (view, record, item, index, ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var arr = ev.getXY();
    arr[0] += 1;
    arr[1] -= 10;
    menu.showAt(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this snippet in all my ExtJS projects:

```
Ext.getBody().on('contextmenu', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
});
```

This disables the default browser context menu in the application. You can add it in your `launch` function.